# Access an element in a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, search, element

I am new to python and am trying to access a single specific element in a list of lists.
I have tried:

```
line_list[2][0]
```

this one isn't right as its a tuple and the list only accepts integers.

```
line_list[(2, 0)]

line_list[2, 0]
```

This is probably really obvious but I just can't see it.

```
def rpd_truncate(map_ref):

    #Munipulate string in order to get the reference value
    with open (map_ref, "r") as reference:
        line_list = []
        for line in reference:
            word_list = []
            word_list.append(line[:-1].split("\t\t"))
            line_list.append(word_list)

    print line_list[2][0]
```

I get the exact same as if I used line_list[2]:

```
['Page_0', '0x00000000', '0x002DF8CD']
```

Comment: The first one is correct - why do you think it doesn't work?  What happened when you tried it?  Also post what `line_list` contains so we can help you.

Comment: you have to show your code. `line_list[2][0]` should work for list of lists, like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. Are you sure you have list of lists? Are you sure you didn't get 'index out of range' exception?

Comment: @Brionius is correct.  Multidimensional array access works this way.  Try `a = [4,5,6] ; b = [a,7,8]; print b[0][2]`

Comment: *this one isn't right as its a tuple and the list only accepts integers.*  A list can contain any Python object, unless you are using some sort of custom list.  Reading elements from a tuple is the same as form a list.  I wonder, are you trying to write new items to a list in this way?  Show us your code and the error message you get.

Comment: First one will work fine on python lists and second, third will work fine on numpy arrays.

Comment: I have edited the original question with the code. The comment about the tuple is about the bottom two attempts. The first attempt got me the closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually split will return a `list`
more over you don't require word_list variable

```
for line in reference:       
    line_list.append(line[:-1].split("\t\t"))
print line_list[2][0]
```